# Facing TypeError: unbound method setUpClass() must be called with HomePageTest instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, selenium

Here the below script which i have tried

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class HomePageTest (unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpClass(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_searchbox(self):
        driver=self
        driver.assertTrue (driver.is_element_present (By.ID,"search"))
        driver.assertTrue (driver.driver.find_element_by_id("search").is_enabled())


    def tearDownClass(self):
     self.driver.quit()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make setUpClass - and tearDownClass - classmethods:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    ...
```

See [the unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass).